# How to make specific text bold

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to make specific text bold, but I really don't know how. Can someone help me?

```
txt_logUser.Text = "Logged user is: " + LogUser;
```

I would like to have bold text that will be in LogUser. What should i do?
Thank for help :)

Comment: what type is txt_logUser? so far I just see a string property. a string only stores characters no formatting

Comment: If you don't need a TextBox because you actually just show the text without input, you could ownerdraw a Label, ie code the Paint event to format the Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with normal textbox and you need to use [RichTextBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) C#

and you can use code something like this.

```
string boldText = "please bold me";

richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

richTextBox1.AppendText(boldText);

richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Regular);

richTextBox1.AppendText(" REGULAR TEXT APPEARS HERE");
```

Output : **please bold me** REGULAR TEXT APPEARS HERE

Answer (score 0):

A `hacky` solution:

create another `label/textBox` something `txt_LogUserBold` make the Font bold. And place your textBoxes/labels near each other like:

> txt_logUser txt_logUserBold

The result will be:

Logged user is: **Something bold**

The first is `txt_logUser`'s text, second is `txt_logUserBold`'s

Comment: I came with this workaround by myself, but I wanted to make it better :D. But thanks for suggestion. @Maruf